# Is it possible to name database tables like Java types?

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql

I want to tables of RDBMS like the names of Java types. Example:

```
mytld.mycompany.myproject.mypackage.mysubpackage.MyClass
```

Currently I am trying to do this with PostgreSQL. It gives me this error:

> FEHLER: falscher qualifizierter Name (zu viele Namensteile):   mytld.mycompany.myproject.mypackage.mysubpackage.MyClass

In English this means something like:

> ERROR: wrong qualified name (to much name parts):   mytld.mycompany.myproject.mypackage.mysubpackage.MyClass

- Wasn't there something like database objects which could be referenced with punctuation names?
- I also may be able to substitute the "." by another character. Is there any robust algorithm to do this?
- Is there a way to use the exact Java class names as database tables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd have to have it in [quotes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) with a limit of 63 characters

```
"mytld.mycompany.myproject.mypackage.mysubpackage.MyClass"
```

Personally, I wouldn't do this. Your database is *not* the java code.

Comment: +1. The answer to his question is not the answer to his problem.

Comment: I second that: don't name your tables like that!

Comment: I am currently writing my own persistence framework. It is based on the thought, that the Java classes already define the entities and no additional domain modeling is needed. Thats why I name tables like Java types. There is a pluggable datastore adapter structure. So other implementations may name the table different.